# save dynamic data using struts and hibernate

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

I have to generate new rows using javascript (thats ok and i done it).

But now I have to save all the rows to the database.

I am a little bit confuse how i do it. Do I provide all data in list to the server? But how?

Answer (score 2):

Do you realize that your question sounds a bit like "Hi, can you teach me Java, DB, JSP, Struts and Hibernate?" It is difficult to provide an answer.

So, assuming you know Java and databases, start with an hibernate tutorial like:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html

Then, may be you should have a look to a Struts tutorial like:
http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial.html

Good luck.